# Android chromecast crash on 2.3

Tags: android, google-cast, chromecast

Our chromecast integration crashes on devices with Android 2.3.x

It is probably caused by some styling attributes overriden by the device vendor and a combination with a reference to Holo styles in the cast SDK / media router…

Tested on Samsung Galaxy S2 and HTC Wildfire 510 SE. Did you experience something like that and have an idea how to fix it?

```
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mycompany.androidclient/com.mycompany.androidclient.FavoritesActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #39: Error inflating class android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:518)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:707)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:215)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1663)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at com.mycompany.androidclient.FavoritesActivity.onCreateInternal(FavoritesActivity.java:170)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at com.mycompany.androidclient.mycompanyComActivity.onCreate(mycompanyComActivity.java:100)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     ... 11 more
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:505)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     ... 26 more
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x7f01000c a=3}
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1907)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:653)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1985)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:121)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     at android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton.<init>(MediaRouteButton.java:117)
01-14 23:49:32.343: E/AndroidRuntime(7298):     ... 29 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark,
Does the Sample app also crash on those devices or it is just the app that you have written? I will try to find a phone running 2.3 (not so easy these days) and test the sample app myself but thought you might have tested that already. If the sample app crashes as well, then it would be much easier for me to debug that and write you back on possible solution.

Comment: We tried the sample code from https://github.com/googlecast/cast-android-sample and it also crashes on the Galaxy S2 with Android 2.3.6. We had lower the minSdkVersion from 13 to 9 (which should be the minimum for the chromecast SDK) to install it on the device.

Comment: I got my hands on a 2.3.4 Samsung phone. When I lowered the minSdkVersion to 9, it complained about the theme but since appcompat (support-v7-appcompat) is used as a library in the project, I changed the application's theme to one of the AppCompat themes:
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" and then compiled and ran the app successfully. What theme are you using? Could you test this change on the Sample app and see if it runs successfully on your phone and if so, try the same change in your app?

Comment: We could solve it by using `@style/Theme.Base.AppCompat`, thanks, Ali!